# nested for loop javascript chess board

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to understand javascript but I can't see why wouldn't this work as a nested loop for a chess board task mentioned in javascript eloquent book. I know the solution and how to do it, but I am just wondering why the code shown below won't work. If someone could explain it. What I was expecting from this code to do is, to make a chess board, but it obviously outputs wrong.So, again I don't need a solution for a chess board, just an explanation of why is this not working. I was expecting that, var board, will get filled with empty fields when first if statement was true, and if that is false, it will get # in addition, until var x is 9, and the statement x%(width-1)==0 becomes true, it gets in to new line. But the output is not as expected. This is the code:

```
     var height = 8; 
     var width = 10;
     var board = "";

     for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {   
       for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
         if ((x + y) % 2 == 0){
           board += " ";
         }
         else if(x%(width-1) == 0){
           board += "\n";
         }
         else{
           board += "#";
           }
        }
     }

     console.log(board);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that both (x + y) % 2 == 0 and x % (width - 1) == 0 (or, simpler, x == width - 1) can hold true at the same time, so which condition check should have priority over the other?

E.g.,

if x == 9 and y == 7, then

(9 + 7) % 2 == 0

So, you should test x against its width bound first for your desired output; i.e., I'd try this, instead:

```
for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {   
   for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
   {
     if (x == width - 1) {
       board += "\n";
     } else if ((x + y) % 2 == 0){
       board += " ";
     }
     else {
       board += "#";
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, so obvious and I still missed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as a nested loop, but the reason for the incorrect output is because your logic is flawed.

reason 1: You actually get x%(width-1)===0 when x is 0 as well (the initialized state) so this triggers two times per inner loop.

reason 2: for every odd value that also would come at a point where x%(width-1)===0 (which again happens twice per inner loop) where there would normally be a '#', there is now a '\n'

If you fix this issue by instead changing this else if statement to:

```
 if(x%(width-1) === 0 && x>0){
     board += "\n";
 }
```

and moving it to the last part of the inner loop, this will work. However, I'm a fan of moving the '\n' addition to the outer loop instead and then you don't need to worry about this logic at all. If you are worried about a newline not appearing before the chessboard (or after, depending on how you code it) then you can do a y>0 check for the newline addition:

```
 var height = 8;
 var width = 10;
 var board = "";

 for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
     if(y>0) board += "\n";
     for (var x = 0; x < width; x++) {
         if ((x + y) % 2 == 0){
             board += " ";
         } else {
             board += "#";
         }
     }
 }

 console.log(board);
```